# SoundCloud iOS SDK outdated?

Tags: ios, sdk, soundcloud, deprecated

I'm developing an iOS application in which I'm planning on integrating SoundCloud. For that, I'm following [SoundCloud's own guide](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/ios-quickstart). Their [official SDK](https://github.com/soundcloud/CocoaSoundCloudAPI) does, however, seem to be outdated. Apart from deprecated code in third party libraries  which the SDK depends upon, their own SDK contains deprecated code.

Are iOS developers still supposed to use this SDK? If not, any recommendations on how to go about?

([Kyle Begeman mentioned the SDK being outdated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849921/streaming-a-users-tracks-from-sound-cloud-to-an-app) in late December 2013, but it hasn't received any attention.)

Comment: I am in the same boat.  I did get the example code to work after:  setting the iOS target to iOS7 in all the external frameworks & I fixed the errors in JSON Kit.

Comment: @M. Bedi: I got it to work as well but there seems to be a rather long delay before a sound is played after launching the play command (I'm using AVaudioplayer). Have you experienced this as well?

Comment: In my limited testing so far, there was a momentary  delay.  I was testing a downloading of a stream over Wifi.

Comment: My problem had nothing to do with SoundCloud, but with AVAudioPlayer as it - if I understand it correctly - has to download the whole audio file prior to playing. AVPlayer seems more suitable.

Comment: I still use it in my app for basic uploading, but there is some evidence that it is not well supported.  I've been sending the api@soundcloud.com email sdk questions and love letters about once every three months for the past two years, and I've yet to get a response.  On the other hand, their github was updated about sep 2013, so that's at least somewhat recent.

Comment: Thanks for the info Michael. I'm surprised there isn't more information on this topic, and even more puzzled by the fact that SC hasn't bothered replying you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The SDK seemed indeed outdated and heavy when I tried to implement it into my project recently. Because of the many unnecessary dependency projects I decided to create a custom library that is much lighter (and hopefully easier to implement).

I put it on GitHub [Here](https://github.com/MrStofkat/LibSoundCloud-iOS)

It is still WIP, but already has functionality build in to search and play tracks as well as get  your own private tracks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing! Looks promising.

Comment: Hello @Dirk de Boer I want to do login with soundcloud can you please help in this i want user info after login thank you

Answer (score 3):

There's a [SoundCloud Cocoapod](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Soundcloud) written in Swift that is actively maintained [on github](https://github.com/delannoyk/SoundcloudSDK) (as of July 2016).